# select2 required field not working in Internet Explorer and Safari

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have several fields that are using select2    v=3.4.1.  I have two of these fields set as required, which works in Chrome and Firefox, but it's not working in IE8.  The validation works and it will show a warning in Chrome and Firefox, and IE11 the warning will display for the first field but not the second field that is enabled by selecting the first.

I have spent far too much time trying to find a work around, but it's just not working.

I know that required is not a supported attribute within early IE and Safari, but is there a way to get these fields required without installing a new plugin?

I am under a confidentiality agreement, but I can post generic code if needed.

DC

Answer (score 0):

http://www.2play4.net/register.html

utilized select2 for the above domain. check if you can try getting your requirement from here. check the Refered By field